# Root password contains character that can't be entered

Tags: linux, ssh, password, root, putty

Don't know what happend really. I changed the root password to a long password containing weird characters, and triple checked that I could log in with it, and has been ever since. *Until now*.

I think the bad character is a ’. How do I enter that in Putty? When I paste the password in Putty, that character and some other are removed/moved. I've set UTF-8 under Window>Translation.

**Update:** `locale` returns the following.

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I've (falsely) assumed it was using UTF-8.

Is there a way to make su read the password from a file?

**Update 2:** I created two files using Notepad++; `ansi.txt` and `utf8.txt`. Both containing the string `abc’def`

`cat ansi.txt` prints `abcdef`
`cat utf8.txt` prints `abcâdef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rackspace actually has a Reset Password button. Go to Hosting>Cloud Servers>[Your server] and click the life saving button.

Be aware that it reboots the server, so open the Console and monitor that the system comes online again fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the "special" character is in fact an accent char (like ' or ```), I could imagine that your current input method converts this character followed, say, by a vowel into an accented char. Entering ' and e on a German keyboard, e.g., will in many cases result in é, similar for ```` and u resulting in ù. 
You could try to enter a space directly after the "special" character to prevent such a conversion. No guarantee, just a guess. (And I hope this answer will appear as I see it now in the preview. ;-))

Comment: When I enter `'[space]`, the row transforms into `(arg: 4)`. I can't enter any characters like `åäö`, Putty just chimes angrily at me. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#!/bin/sh
su - << _EOF_
password goes here
_EOF_
```

Put it in a file tmpPassFix then run

```
chmod +x tmpPassFix
./tmpPassFix
```

Untested may or may not work. This is assuming you can get password into the "tmpPassFix" file above.
I don't know much about encodings, but if you can get it in windows you could do the above and then winscp it over, providing the script works.

Comment: `su: must be run from a terminal` unfortunately it did not work